# face recognition to detect mood

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, kinect

I'm looking for a specific form of facial recognition. I want to detect he mood of face in a given image, e.g. whether it is smiling or sad. Are there any .NET libraries for this?

Comment: Haha this isn't like Numb3rs where you can write a face detection program in an hour;)

Answer (score 7):

You should take a look at [face.com](http://face.com/), it is a popular face recognition API. You can read a tutorial about [using it with C# here](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/08/using-face-api-in-c/). You can detect [happy / sad via the mood API](http://developers.face.com/newsletters/july-2011-moods-and-facial-expressions/).

Comment: ... and all that took was one Google search ;-)

Comment: @Gabriel agreed - it was a pretty useless stack overflow question, but I think I have found my next 'friday afternoon' project ;-)

Comment: Hi i am using **kinect** device for the face mood detection returns can u help we with c# code

Answer (score 2):

Building on @ColinE's face.com suggestion here is a website that list how to get the moods with example C# code: http://www.ginktage.com/2011/08/using-face-api-in-c/

It does look like you may need to park the image somewhere as the API is expecting a url not a raw image stream. 
To save from Kinect follow the tutorial on channel9 Camera Fundamentals and then save the bitmap with bitmap.save() . Easy peasy.

Another google search.

I would have just posted this as a comment but I can't yet.

Comment: You should be happy that you posted it as an answer, +1